# Inserting form data into mysql using nodejs. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

So I am working on a web-app for my school wherein I am supposed to create a login register page. I decided to use node, express, and mysql for this. I have just started to learn node and am a novice. Given below is the code I made for inserting data from the register form into the mysql database table (I have already connected to database earlier successfully):

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const firstname = req.body.first_name
        const lastname = req.body.last_name
        const email = req.body.email_id
        const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        res.redirect("/login")
    } catch {
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
     const sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES ('"+firstname+"', '"+lastname+"','"+email+"', '"+hashedPass+"')"
        con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err
        console.log('New user registered: ' + users)
        })
})
app.listen(3000)
```

However when I refresh the server using nodemon and input test data into the form to check whether users are getting registered or not, the following error is displayed on the terminal:

```
Connected to mysql database!
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Connected to mysql database!
(node:60021) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: firstname is not defined
    at /Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/server.js:55:92
(node:60021) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:60021) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Connected to mysql database!
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Connected to mysql database!
(node:60021) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: firstname is not defined
    at /Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/server.js:55:92
(node:60021) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:60021) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have no idea as to what is going on. Please help me out with this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`const firstname` is scoped to the `try` block but you try to read it **outside** of the block.

Comment: Will that be the same for the other constants not using the brcrypt function as well? (i.e. '''const lastname''' and '''const email'''?

Comment: So I put the constants out of the try catch block and now it says that the hashesPass in not defined. How is that possible? (Giving an unhandled promised rejection error warning)